# How to filter NSmutableArray according to float

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I'm loading a NSMutableArray using NScoding; this loads up just fine:

```
_patients = [RND_PatientDB loadPatientData];
```

Each object of the _Patients NSMutableArray has a float called "completed".

I try to filter only the objects from NSmutableArray of "_pateints" that have the _patients.completed == 1 :

```
NSNumber *num1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"completed == %@", num1];
patientsFiltered = [[_patients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate] mutableCopy];
```

I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key completed.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have a doubt, whay to define completed as float and not bool?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case you defined 'completed' as float in Model, you should use

```
float num1 = 1.0f;
NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"completed == %f", num1];
```

Below is correct when you have wrapped float in NSNumber in data model.

```
NSNumber *num1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
```

Comment: Thank you @bllakjakk I tried your suggestion and It still crashes when I load the app    

    `2014-09-21 11:20:21.819 Rounds[12492:583095] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<RND_Patient 0x7bf6c2f0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key completed.`

Comment: Based on your added logs in comment: Either you used an incorrect key, or you initialized your managed object with init instead of initWithEntity:inManagedObjectContext:. **Please edit your question with further part of NSMnagagedObject initialization code**. Also Spell check patients.

Comment: Thank you @bllakjakk I fixed the issue by using `NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.completed == %f", num1];` which is the correct key.